# Use PHP script to backup database without using Mysqldump, any recommended CLASS？

Tags: mysql, class, backup

Unfortunately, the hosting can't use `mysqldump` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) includes this functionality.  You may want to look into how they do this.

Comment: I tried to and found the code in phpMyAdmin is really hard to me. :(

Comment: It's going to be necessarily complicated, because you are basically re-implementing mysqldump - you have to support pretty much every feature that a database table or column can have.  It's surprising that you can't use mysqldump if you have shell access.  Do they block access to the command-line mysql clients?